# Adding In Original Sheet Name With IMPORTRANGE, QUERY, in an Array Formula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, import, label, google-query-language

Basically I am trying to import several different tabs from one Google Sheets doc and then have that data aggregated into a separate single tab
on a different Google Sheets doc with an extra column indicating which sheet that data originally came from.

So for an example
If my Aggregation sheet was here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1855Y-TzHtXZi-0g_-Jh8LxuqI0rdJasoSKi9YBkGfs8/edit#gid=0

And my raw data was coming from multiple sheets/tabs (in this example Store 1 and 2) here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yar_i4-KdVOT-IgjgUNij48R9yuH-gFNprZgl0X7S94/edit#gid=0

What can be added to my currently functioning formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY({
(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yar_i4-KdVOT-IgjgUNij48R9yuH-gFNprZgl0X7S94/edit#gid=0","'Store 1'!A2:G"))
},"select * where Col1 is not Null"))
```

to make sure in the [Aggregation Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1855Y-TzHtXZi-0g_-Jh8LxuqI0rdJasoSKi9YBkGfs8/edit#gid=0), I can tell where that data originally came from by having that source sheet/tab name (Store 1 or 2) in a column?

I have had some success using a similar formula as this in the past to accomplish the same thing:

```
    =ArrayFormula(QUERY({
'Store1'!A2:G,IF(N('Store1'!A2:G),"Store1");
'Store2'!A2:G,IF(N('Store2'!A2:G),"Store2")
},"select * where Col1 is not Null"))
```

But adding in the IMPORTRANGE functionality in this case seems to prevent that from working :(

Feel free to edit that example Aggregator sheet

If I am completely on the wrong track here feel free to let me know, just wanted to share what has been tried.

Thank you so much for the assistance in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({
 QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1yar_i4-KdVOT-IgjgUNij48R9yuH-gFNprZgl0X7S94", "Store 1!A2:G"), 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,'Store 1' label 'Store 1'''");
 QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1yar_i4-KdVOT-IgjgUNij48R9yuH-gFNprZgl0X7S94", "Store 2!A2:G"), 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,'Store 2' label 'Store 2'''")}, 
 "where Col1 is not null")
```

[image]